# Regular Expression for GY1-9 postcodes

Tags: php, regex, drupal, drupal-7, ubercart

I'm trying to make a case insensitive regular expression for my shipping section that catches all postcodes which start with GY1 - GY9 (single figures only). So far, it catches all gy postcodes, not just 1-9. Here is what I have so far:

```
^[gG][yY][1-9]{1}
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

I used the following regex based on stema's answer below:

```
^[gG][yY][1-9]\s?[1-9][a-zA-Z]{2}$
```

Comment: Please give an example of a postcode it should not catch but that it catches. I ask because your regular expression looks fine to me.

Comment: it could be GY1 1aa or GY15HG

Comment: For being valid or invalid? What would be a valid example, what an invalid one? If you're unclear about what should be matched, it's hard to write a regex ;)

Comment: For being valid and the format is always GY then 1-9 then optional space then 1 digit and then 2 letters. the GY and last 2 letters need to be case insensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
/^GY[1-9](?!\d)/i
```

Your regex matches because there can be anything following your digit.

- I use the negative lookahead assertion `(?!\d)` to ensure that there is not a digit after your `[1-9]`.
- The flag `i` at the end makes the regex matching case insensitive, so no need for `[gG][yY]`

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?303rf)

**Edit:**

When the second part can has only 1 leading digit you can try this

```
^GY[1-9]\s?[1-9][a-z]{2}
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?303rr)

Means starts with "GY" then a digit from 1-9, followed by an optional space, then another digit and two letters.

Comment: The only problem with this is that the second part of the postcode starts with a digit followed by two letters and might have a space after the GY number or not, e.g. the first postcode is GY1 1aa and you could also have GY15HG.

Comment: @PhilFaceplantYoung the second part starts all the time with one digit or can there be also 2 digit e.g. GY1 23AA/GY123AA?

Comment: It's always one number and two letters following the first part. Does it still need the /i on it? e.g. ^GY[1-9]\s?[1-9][a-z]{2}/i ?

Comment: @PhilFaceplantYoung then my last edit is what you want. If the string ends after this, you can add a `$` to match the end of the string, if not then add a `\b` to match a word boundary. This is to ensure that there are no more word characters following.

Comment: the string does end then, but how do is the best way to make the whole string case insensitive? Is it `^[gG][yY][1-9]\s?[1-9][a-zA-Z]{2}$`?

Comment: @PhilFaceplantYoung the best thing is to use the `i` modifier like in my first example.

Answer (score 1):

> For being valid and the format is always GY then 1-9 then optional space then 1 digit and then 2 letters. the GY and last 2 letters need to be case insensitive.

That description can be transposed into a regular expression right away:

```
~^gy[1-9] ?\d[a-z]{2}$~i
```

Read as:

- `~` pattern delimiter
- `^` start of string
- `gy` (literal)
- `[1-9]` 1 ... 9
- `?` optional space
- `\d` one digit
- `[a-z]{2}` two letters
- `$` end of string
- `~` pattern delimiter
- `i` case insensitive - `gy` as well as `[a-z]` are matching both upper and lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

```
var reg=/^[gG][yY][1-9]$/
```

GY1
Gy1
gY1
gy1  .....

Answer (score 0):

```
 '/^gy\d{1}$/i'
```

That should fix it. The $ says that the \d{1} should be the ending of the string, so it will accept "GY1" through "gy9", but not "GY12". Note that case sensitivity is easily done with the `i` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = '/^GY[0-9]( )?[0-9][A-Z]{2}?$/i';
$codes = array(
    'GY1 AAA',
    'GY2 2BX',
    'GY 545',
    'gy5 5rt1',
    'GY15HG',
    'GY10 8FG'
);

foreach( $codes as $code ){

    echo $code, ': ';
    if ( preg_match( $pattern, $code ) ){
        echo 'valid';
    }
    else { echo 'invalid'; }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

prints

```
GY1 AAA: invalid
GY2 2BX: valid
GY 545: invalid
gy5 5rt1: invalid
GY15HG: valid
GY10 8FG: invalid
```